# Bash host check two columns

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have column A and column B that conatins hostnames. If host answer from first line of column A then continiue to second line of column A. If host dont answer from column A then check the host from the same line of column B. If the second host from B column doesnt answer then print error host down.

Comment: You have a column where? Textfile? stdout? Piped output? something else. Details with examples, please.

Comment: The column are in a text file

Answer (score 0):

["How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
while read -r host1 host2; do
  somethingsomething "$host1" || somethingsomething "$host2" || { echo "#fail" >&2 ; }
done < input.lst
```